# SQL: Converting columns into row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can some please help to write a query which gives me the desired output as shown in Table2? Table 1 will always display one record (row)

Table 1: Current output

```
| ColumnA | ColumnB |ColumnC |ColumnD|
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   | Cell 3   | Cell 4   |
```

Table 2: Desired Output

```
| NewColumn1 | NewColumn2|
| -------- | -------- |
| ColumnA  | Cell 1  |
| ColumnB  | Cell 2 |
| ColumnC  | Cell 3  |
| ColumnD| Cell 4 |
```

Unpivot didn't work for me

Comment: *"Unpivot didn't work for me"* why didn't it? What was the attempt? Unpivot would certainly work here.

Answer (score 2):

If the source will ALWAYS be ONE record, otherwise you would need to use this approach in a `CROSS APPLY`

```
 Select [Key]
       ,[Value]
  From  OpenJson(  (Select * From YourTable For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )  )
```

**Results**

```
Key     Value
ColumnA Cell 1
ColumnB Cell 2
ColumnC Cell 3
ColumnD Cell 4
```